# caffe: can not change pad size of pooling layer

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe, conv-neural-network

when changing pas size, I get this error. I tried different pad sizes, but I am getting similar errors. here is more details:

```
    layer {
  name: "Pooling1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "Convolution2"
  top: "Pooling1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_h: 1
    kernel_w: 2
    stride_h: 1
    stride_w: 2
    pad_h: 0
    pad_w: 3
  }
```

This is the error:

```
...
Creating layer Convolution2
I0525 10:45:37.403520 20575 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer Convolution2
I0525 10:45:37.403524 20575 net.cpp:406] Convolution2 <- Concat1
I0525 10:45:37.403529 20575 net.cpp:380] Convolution2 -> Convolution2
I0525 10:45:37.403555 20575 net.cpp:122] Setting up Convolution2
I0525 10:45:37.403560 20575 net.cpp:129] Top shape: 1 16 1 4076 (65216)
I0525 10:45:37.403563 20575 net.cpp:137] Memory required for data: 3022080
I0525 10:45:37.403568 20575 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer Pooling1
I0525 10:45:37.403571 20575 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer Pooling1
I0525 10:45:37.403575 20575 net.cpp:406] Pooling1 <- Convolution2
I0525 10:45:37.403581 20575 net.cpp:380] Pooling1 -> Pooling1
F0525 10:45:37.403594 20575 pooling_layer.cpp:74] Check failed: pad_w_ < kernel_w_ (3 vs. 2)
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is very clear from the error message you get: you set your pad to be larger than the pooling kernel size. Reduce the pad and you should be okay

Comment: then the size of my top is changing and not compatible for the next layer!

Comment: i wanna have a top: 1x16x1x2044; but if pad=1 then top:1x16x1x2038! how to increase top size then?

Comment: @NimaHatami look at [receptive field arithmetics](https://medium.com/mlreview/a-guide-to-receptive-field-arithmetic-for-convolutional-neural-networks-e0f514068807)  you might want to play with you kernel size?

Comment: @NimaHatami your input shape is too small to get the output shape you expect. What are you trying to achieve here? you might need to pad some other layers...

Comment: I was trying to sum this top (1x16x1x2038) with another top of size 1x16x1x2044. I decided to get this by adding the previous conv layer and it works well!